# How to define array request in GraphQL in magento2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.4, graphql, array, magento-2-commerce

How to define **details array** in the below request:

```
query{
  results(
    id: "56",
    details: 
      {
        name: "yamini",
        bloodGroup: "AB+"
        age:25
      }
    )
  {
    message
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Try This To Pass Array in Query**

```
{
  results(id: "56", details: [
    {
      name: "yamini", 
      bloodGroup: "AB+", 
      age: 25
    }, 
    {
      name: "Yerusu", 
      bloodGroup: "AB-", 
      age: 22
    }
   ]
  ) {
    message
  }
}
```

For More : https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/graphql/schema/cart/mutations/add-products/

Comment: getting this error: 1 exception(s):\nException #0 (GraphQL\\Error\\SyntaxError): Syntax Error: Unterminated string.\n\nException #0 (GraphQL\\Error\\SyntaxError): Syntax Error: Unterminated string.\n<pre>#1 GraphQL\\Language\\Lexer->readToken() called at [

Comment: Please share your schema and your resolver file. For more information. Please update your question.